# Cannot Execute Application in JAR file from command line

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, jar

I have a relatively simple java application I am running from intelliJ. It's a maven-based build. It runs fine from within intellij.

My problem (embarrassing..) is I am having trouble getting it to run from the command line. I've attempted both from the jar that is built, and from the classes directory.

Ideally I would like to run it from the jar. The jar has a single application with a main method. I build from the command line "mvn clean package", and the the target directory is created with all the needed components. My expectation is that this is an executable jar file, since it has the class with the main method. However, I run the following command by opening DOS shell (windows) as admin
:

```
$ java -jar /c/Users/tclotworthy/Iamus/satelliteProj/paging-mission-control/paging-mission-control-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
Error: Unable to access jarfile C:/Users/tclotworthy/Iamus/satelliteProj/paging-mission-control/paging-mission-control-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

If I could upload the jar file here, I would so that others can attempt. I would be grateful for any suggestions on how to overcome my problem. Thank you

Comment: 1. Having a main class is not enough. You need a manifest file in META-INF/ folder that déclarés what is your main class. 2. Why dont you try to run tour java command from the folder where the jar is ? And why using Unix style file path in windows ?

Comment: @SebPerp thanks for response. Ok. I did what you suggested and ran it directly in the directory where jar file is. Finds jar now, but getting this error:
"no main manifest attribute, in paging-mission-control-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar". I don't know how to update the jar file so that the manifest has the proper attribute. Thanks for any response.

Comment: Since JVM couldn't access the file, check whether it's actually located under provided path. It seems like the path doesn't lead to a build folder.

Comment: As @SebPerp mentioned you have to either specify main file in the manifest ([docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/appman.html)) or specify main file at command line with `java -cp file.jar com.example.MainClass`. Also to make it work you need all the dependencies be assembled in a jar or specify them at command line

Comment: you typed `/c/...` and the error is `C:/...` ? I cannot reproduce that - I would try `java -jar C:\Users\tclotworthy\...` **and** check that the file is really there (e.g. `dir C:\Users\tclotworthy\...`) **BUT** I also wonder the `$ ` prompt - not usual for DOS (Windows command line) more like CYGWIN or similar (GIT bash, ...) which would also explain that `/c/...` got `C:/...`

Comment: thanks to all. I was able to make more progress by adding maven jar plugin with the manifest. I will answer the solution myself, but you guys were helpful in getting me to think it through. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

I had multiple problems. First, I was using unix-style path rather than windows-style path. Second, I did not have the manifest properly set up to make the jar file executable. I added the following to the pom.xml:

```
build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <!-- Build an executable JAR -->
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                        <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
                        <mainClass>paging_mission_control.SatApplication</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

So, now it finds the application.